# Как использовать функционал кнопки только тогда, когда она VISIBLE?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, textview

Уважаемые разработчики! Задача состоит в следующем...
Есть 2 TextView и 1 Button(внутрь вложен Toast). Все элементы android:visibility="invisible. Когда стартует аппа, то сначала с помощью анимации появляется первый TextView, он пропадает, опять же с помощью анимации и за ним сразу же вылетает второй TextView с анимацией. Первый TextView во время своей работы меняет несколько раз свою видимость invisible -> visible -> invisible. Второй TextView меняет свою видимость только единожды invisible -> visible. Когда второй TextView отработал, он остаётся на экране, а под ним появляется кнопка(invisible -> visible) тоже с помощью анимации. Проблема в следующем: пока кнопка не стала видимой, она всё равно выполняет нажатие даже при своём invisible состоянии. Как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопка становилась рабочей и выполняла свою логику при нажатии только тогда, когда она станет visible?

Comment: так и проверять ``if btn.isVisible() {do your stuff}`` (псевдокод)

Comment: @Эникейщик , сейчас попробую

Comment: @Эникейщик, я может чего-то не так делаю, но на кнопку можно нажать,даже когда она скрыта с экрана, тоаст всё равно вылетает. Просто по коду она у меня скрыта только определённое кол-во времени, пока второй tv не появился. Может появление кнопку нужно как-то обернуть в функцию отдельную от второго tv?

Comment: Совершенно точно что-то не так.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а можешь подсказать как написать "если анимация tv отработала, то только тогда кнопка становиться видимой и выполняет свой функционал" ?

Comment: А вы какой способ анимации используете? Не старый ли? Я на этом тоже обжегся.

Comment: @Style-7, я сделал один файл анимации, который включает в себя код из fade_in & fade_out. Добавил эту анимацию к 1му tv, он отработал, следущий анимация для 2го tv появляется через startOffset = 5000, tv.startAnimation(animation), tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE. Ну а дальше кнопка, которая тоже появляется с анимацие, когда 2ой tv VISIBLE, только вот tv, наверное, постоянно видим для кнопки и поэтому он работает, хоть и не показывается на экране.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли.  класс ValueAnimator или Animation ?

Comment: @Style-7, Animation

Comment: Используйте ValueAnimator, и этот глюк уйдет

Comment: @Style-7, буду пробовать, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать View.GONE вместо View.INVISIBLE. Это решит вашу проблему но может повлиять на верстку. Поэтому если этот вариант вам не подходит то адаптируй вариант из комментариев.

```
button.setOnClickListener { 
        if(it.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            // show toast
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, заработало, но вёрстка накрылась :(

Comment: Ну либо адаптируйте верстку либо попробуйте вариант с проверкой на View.VISIBLE

Comment: Много ломать придётся в верстке, поэтому пытаюсь сделать через проверку, но не выходит пока ничего хорошо, но спасибо за совет!

Comment: А может вы знаете как сделать проверку "если анимация tv отработала, то только тогда кнопка становиться видимой и выполняет свой функционал" ?

Comment: Реализуйте через enabled. Деактивируйте вашу кнопку setEnabled. Попробуйте дать вашей анимации слушатель setAnimationListener. И в методе onAnimationEnd включайте вашу кнопку обратно setEnabled.

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо.